# Commutative rings of characteristic 2

Tags: ring-theory

Is there a "canonical" form to write the commutative rings of characteristic $2$?

For instance, I hoped that every such ring is isomorphic to ${\cal P}(X)$ with symmetric difference as addition and intersection of sets as multiplication -- but quid's comment below shows that I'm mistaken in that belief. Nevertheless, ${\cal P}(X)$ has some "nice canonical twang" to it, so I still hope it can be involved in some description of rings of characteristic $2$.

Comment: Your 'for instance' cannot be true since this would imply that there is a unique ring of characteristic $2$ for each cardinality. This is not the case already for $4$. Consider the finite field and the direct product of two fields of cardinality $2$/

Comment: Thanks - I will edit my post to include your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ with the operations you describe contains zero divisors when $|X|>1$, you will be at a loss to describe any domain of characteristic two, for example.

What's more, the multiplication you're describing on the powerset makes the ring (and all of its subrings) a Boolean ring, which is only a small subclass of rings of characteristic 2.

Rings of sets *do* come into play in the study of Boolean rings. Perhaps you're already aware of that, but if you aren't, look into [Stone's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras).

Commutative rings of characteristic $2$ can be quite pathological (just think of what you can do with quotients of multivariate polynomial rings over $\Bbb F_2$.)